# Blank PHP page with no errors

Tags: php

I made a simple sign up to newsletter form earlier today and worked perfectly fine. But now, I realized that the script might be vulnerable to CSRF, so an easy fix was to add Google's reCaptcha API. When I wanted to test the script, it showed me nothing but a blank page even though I had no errors.

**Script**

```
<?php 
if($_POST['submit']){ 
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "private_key";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
          $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
          $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
          $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
   // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
   die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
        "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
   } else { 

       $to = 'email@domain.com';
       $mail_list = $_POST['mail_list'];
       $subject = 'New sign up';
       $headers = 'From: '. $mail_list .'';
       if (!filter_var($mail_list, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
              $dodgy_strings = array(
                   "content-type:"
                   ,"mime-version:"
                   ,"multipart/mixed"
                   ,"bcc:"
       );

        function is_valid_email($mail_list) {
          return preg_match('#^[a-z0-9.!\#$%&\'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@([0-9.]+|([^\s]+\.+[a-z]{2,6}))$#si', $mail_list);
        }

        function contains_bad_str($str_to_test) {
          $bad_strings = array(
                        "content-type:"
                        ,"mime-version:"
                        ,"multipart/mixed"
                            ,"Content-Transfer-Encoding:"
                        ,"bcc:"
                            ,"cc:"
                            ,"to:"
          );

          foreach($bad_strings as $bad_string) {
            if(eregi($bad_string, strtolower($str_to_test))) {
              echo "<script>alert('". $bad_string ." found. Suspected injection attempt - mail not being sent.');</script>";
              exit;
            }
          }
        }

        function contains_newlines($str_to_test) {
           if(preg_match("/(%0A|%0D|\\n+|\\r+)/i", $str_to_test) != 0) {
             echo "<script>alert('newline found in ". $str_to_test .". Suspected injection attempt - mail not being sent.');</script>";
             exit;
           }
        } 


        if (!is_valid_email($mail_list)) {
          echo "<script>alert('Invalid email submitted - mail not being sent.');</script>";
          exit;
        }

        contains_bad_str($mail_list);
        contains_bad_str(body);
        mail($to, $subject, $mail_list, $headers);
      }
    }
  }   
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>List</title>
 <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="mail_list" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up" />
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="public_key"></div>   
   <?php
     require_once('recaptchalib.php');
     $publickey = "public_key"; // you got this from the signup page
     echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
   ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that if there was actually an error that I did not notice, it's because I am new to PHP and I use this [site](http://phpcodechecker.com/) to handle errors.

Regards.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: blank pages DOES mean (potential) errors and you're not looking for them http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php or your system's not setup to catch/log/display.

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: The page is still blank and did not display any type of errors, and I am testing directly through my godaddy domain so I am sure that it supports PHP. @Dagon

Comment: If the problem was that your account has no PHP support, you would see the raw PHP code being delivered to your browser.

Comment: browser - view source- do you see code?

Comment: Nothing at all. What I did now was that I removed the first line and now got an error saying "Notice: Undefined index: recaptcha_challenge_field"

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so I found this solution. If anyone else faces this kind of issue, do the following.

> **First:**
>
> Copy the JavaScript tag (that Google gives you) and add it inside your HTML head or at the end of the body tag.
>
> **Second:**
>   Add the div tag under your submit button or wherever you want as long as it's inside your form.

Now you need to verify if users actually answered the captecha or not; so inside your php simply write this.

**PHP script**

```
 if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']){
       // checks if the captecha is empty or not
       $secret = "your_secret_key";
       // The secret key is the one on your right.
       $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
       // The end user's ip address.
       $captecha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

       $resp = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captecha&remoteip=$ip");
       // code turns the resp variable to JSON
       $arr = json_decode($resp,TRUE);
       // decodes the json
       if($arr['success']){
        // if success write the rest of your php else show an error
       }
```

Hope it helps.